# Easy infinite scroll jQuery with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to do a really simple infinite scroll that checks in a `.html` file whenever the scroll is at the bottom, then loads the content of another `.html` file (which is more text).

The second HTML file (the one that will be loaded whenever you scroll to the "limit" and make the "infinite scroll", is this one "Ej7.1.html":

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p> lorem ipsum etc etc etc </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are more `<p> lorem ipsum`with more text, but to make it shorter to read in here, I'm taking that out.

And the first HTML file which I am trying to implement the jQuery version for is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script> src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" </script>
    </head>

    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() –    $(window).height()) {
            // Here goes the Ajax
                 $("body").load("Ej7.1");
            }
        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <h1> Pagina ej 7</h1>

        <p> lorem ipsum and a lot of text </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the error it gives me opening the `html` and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> is a syntax error in `–    $(window).height()) {` as an `unexpected identifier`error.

I think I am having a syntax error, but I cannot seem to find what I am missing out nor doing wrong.

Comment: You'll also need the '.html' for your ajax request = "Ej7.1.html" http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The `<script>` tag is outside the `<head>` and `<body>` tags. I'm not sure if that is legal or not for well-formed HTML. Using [the W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) indicates it is not: *"Error: script element between head and body."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong character for minus.

You're using `–` (char code: 8211). You should use `-` (char code: 45). There could be something wrong with your keyboard or you copy pasted it from some non-properly formatted source.

Also, your jQuery inclusion tag won't work as spotted by [@agmcleod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449616/4802649).

That line is basically doing this:

```
<script>
    src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
</script>
```

If you `console.log(src)` on your page you'll see this:

> `"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"`.

Answer (score 4):

Your script tag is mis-formatted. Put the src attribute in the tag itself:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```